# Ubuntu 16.04 Crashing After Suspend

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, suspend

I have the following problem:

Every time I suspend my laptop and then try to wake it up, it starts loading and crashes immediately. I can see that it tries to wake up because of the light but just dies after.

The configuration is Lenovo e540 with Nvidia GeForce 740M. I had the problem before because of the BIOS version and after I upgraded the BIOS it worked for two days and back to the same problem. I am suspicious that it is probably the graphic card which is why I tried 4 different versions of the Nvidia driver but no success.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vGCMGkMNNb/

This is what the syslog looks like. I put the laptop to sleep around 13:27 and then tried to wake it up immediately after.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2KVQz2QCNc/

Here is a link to the Xorg log.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably nVidia + Intel graphics to choose from, try to switch via nvidia-prime option in nvidia settings to Intel, then logout, login and if everything goes ok, then try to suspend and wake up, if issue still occurs it may be ubuntu 16.xx common issue which may disappears after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04. If laptop wakes up then use this Intel mode till the upgrade to 18.04 will come. If You won't be able to login after switching to Intel then switch to tty text mode (e.g alt+ctrl+f3 or f4) login thru this mode and type `sudo prime-select nvidia` and go back to graphical mode via alt+ctrl+f1
In my opinion it's something with acpi or other Ubuntu 16.04 issue which was solved but not in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried what you suggested but the problem is still there :(